# Multiply variable ranges with Bash brace expansion

Tags: bash, shell, math, brace-expansion

I've a question extending the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690102/how-can-i-make-a-multiplication-table-using-bash-brace-expansion-so-far-i-have-t): Can you multiply two **variable** ranges in Bash using brace expansion (not `seq`) and not using loops?

**This is what I've tried so far**

Work out how variable boundary ranges work (finally, a good use of `eval`):

```
$ echo {1..10}
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
$ boundary=10
$ echo {1..$boundary}
{1..10}
$ eval echo {1..$boundary}
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

But how can you multiply two variable boundary ranges?

```
$ echo $(({1..10}*{1..10}))
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60 7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 70 8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72 80 9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 90 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
$ boundary=10
$ echo $(({1..$boundary}*{1..$boundary}))
bash: {1..10}*{1..10}: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "{1..10}*{1..10}")
$ eval echo $(({1..$boundary}*{1..$boundary}))
bash: {1..10}*{1..10}: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "{1..10}*{1..10}")
```

Comment: So, indulge me: you repost someone else's contrived question and expect this not to be closed as an exact duplicate **because of:.....**?

Comment: You could have pointed out that I should make my point clear, but two comments crying "duplicate" are non-productive.

Comment: I _was_ pointing it out. You don't like how I did that. I'll try to tred lightly next time.

Comment: Hehe. I didn't know that voting for duplicate also comments on that. I see that the 'other person' was me. **Enlightenment**

Comment: See [How can I use $var in a shell brace expansion of a sequence?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7738/885) at [Unix Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Gilles: That's what I have in the first code block. The question is in the second block and the answer's not in your link.

Comment: So any pointers to where in the bash man page is '$[]' documented?

Comment: @nhed: `man bash`, search `$[`, first hit. It's an obsolete form of arithmetic expression, the preferred syntax is `$((2*3))`.

Comment: @Gilles: Didn't know `$[` was deprecated. Updated the question.

Comment: @Giles I did search for `$[` didn't find it.  I always use `$(())` but it didnt seem to work for this case, even with escaping.  Also - how did you fix my answer to not need an additional set of slashes (formatting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this seems to work, just escaped the `$` and `[]` to delay their evaluation (so that they are echoed, then evaluated)

```
eval echo \$\[{1..$boundary}*{1..$boundary}\]
```

That said I now need to go lookup what `$[]` does    ;-)

---

Second answer, with non deprecated `$[]` syntax (but two evals)

`eval eval echo "\$\(\("{1..$boundary}*{1..$boundary}"\)\)"`

or

`eval eval echo \\\$\\\(\\\({1..$boundary}*{1..$boundary}\\\)\\\)`

Comment: Pretty nifty. Remember to initialize `boundary`

Comment: They initialized boundry in his question - i just replaced the non working line

Comment: Use four spaces at the beginning of a line for a code block (you can use the `{}` button or `Ctrl+K`). This is by far the most useful markup here.

Comment: Are the backslashes preceding the first `$` needed? Seems to work without.